# conjure-up Ubuntu Server 17.04 OpenStack Nova LXD

Tags: conjure-up

I ran through the conjure-up setup for Ubuntu Server 17.04 OpenStack Nova LXD. 
It completed successfully.

The only difference between the setup video and my install was that I ran the setup through an SSH shell as I'm not running a Desktop OS.

Presumably this is why it did not provide the instructions for how to connect to the management IP ( `http://"horizon-ip"/horizon` ). I'm guessing that the WebUI component is running in an lxd container.

How do I gain access to the WebUI from my network? I assumed this would be the preferred manner of access since this is all running in a cloud, but the conjure-up setup seems to think all access would be local.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by one of these two way:

1. **Add one rule to the iptables**

   In this case, you should just run this command.

   ```
   sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination <<horizon-ip>>:443
   ```

   you can access to **horizon** dashborad via `https://<<horizon-ip>>/horizon`
2. **Setup NginX**

   `sudo apt install nginx`

   add these configuration to `vim /etc/nginx/site-enables/openstack.conf`

   ```
   server {
     listen  81;
     server_name <<server-ip>>;

     location / {
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_pass http://<<horizon-ip>>/;
     }
   ```

   `sudo service nginx reload`

   Now you can access to the **horizon** dashboard via `http://<<server-ip>>:81/horizon`